# node-gyp crashing on a basic Buffer::Length operation about incompatible types

Tags: node.js, buffer, v8, node-gyp

I've took a simple piece of code from the NodeJS core (crypto) :

```
ASSERT_IS_BUFFER(args[0]);
ssize_t klen = Buffer::Length(args[0]);
```

However when compiling this with `node-gyp` in my own native extension, I get the following error :

```
../deps/v8/include/v8.h:202:5: error: assigning to 'v8::Object *volatile' from incompatible type
      'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^
../deps/v8/include/v8.h:145:37: note: expanded from macro 'TYPE_CHECK'
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
                                    ^
../src/openssljs.cc:300:33: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::Handle<v8::Object>::Handle<v8::Value>'
      requested here
                ssize_t klen = Buffer::Length(args[0]);
                                              ^
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You took those lines from one version of node (e.g. from HEAD) but header files in your system belong to other version of node.

In the old version `Buffer::Length` was accepting `v8::Handle<v8::Object>` while in newer it accepts `v8::Handle<v8::Value>` which matches the type of `args[0]`.

Commit that changed the signature: https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/c8c638a84195e5571f4ece881375909e1f4b82a8

You can either update node.js installed in your system or use an explicit cast: `args[0].As<Object>()`

Comment: The explicit cast worked but it is strange as I do have node v0.8.14 installed on my system (OSX macports). I do have indeed the wrong headers in `/opt/local/include/node`.